# Bisulfate vs Bisulfite to neutralize off gassing in paint

Tags: ions

I need to neutralize the off gassing in wall paint that contains one or more of the antimicrobial compounds of  isothiazolinone, chloromethylisothiazolinone, methylisothiazolinone, benzisothiazolinone, or octylisothiazolinone.

I applied and used sodium bisulfate rather than sodium bisulfite. Do I need to now rinse it off and find the sodium bisulfite or will the sodium bisulfate work?

[Link to study using sodium bisulfite.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9471981)

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to learn more about this site. In particular, no one here can (or will) give medical advice. Good luck!

Comment: I am not a doctor. In this case, my first suggestion would be to leave the area and hire someone to apply bisulfite and another coat of a different paint. The two compounds will have very different [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bisulfite).

Comment: I am just trying to find out if bisulfite and bisulfate are totally different things. I have the room sealed off and medical treatment has already been  administered. I found this site while searching for answers about what the difference between the two chemicals sodium bisulfite and sodium bisulfate are. I can simply wait 2 months to open up the room again, but could really use the space to work as it is my home office. Thank you for any help.

Comment: To closevoters: Am I misinterpreting the question? Since I don't see how this is medical advice. For now I removed the background.

Comment: Yes, bisulfate and bisulfite are two completely different things.

Comment: Related: [Sodium Bisulfate vs Sodium Bisulfite](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/17321/7951)

Comment: I feel the question @Loong found is sufficiently close to warrant a duplicate closing.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you all for the help. I sincerely appreciate your wisdom. A chemist, I am certainly not! I was able to find the sodium bisulfite at a home brewing/wine making store. I am going to try that to see if it will neutralize the off gassing chemicals in the paint. According to a scientific study in Sweden, it "should" work to neutralize the chloromethylisothiazolinone (an antimicrobial additive) in the paint. From now on, I will stick to organic milk paint, so as not to cause an allergic reaction to my husband!
Sincerely Cathy C.